# Azure ARM template dependsOn not working (succeeds on redeploy)

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template, azure-resource-group

When I create an AKS cluster using ARM templates with `SystemAssigned` in the `identity` field, there's a secondary resource group in the form `MC_<rg_name>_<cluster_name>_location` that's created. Inside this group is a managed identity in the form `<cluster-name>-agentpool` that `Kubelet` uses.

The arm template will be at the bottom of the post but the general structure is as follows. The reason I have them in separate deployments is because I deploy things at the **subscription** level:

```
Deployment A
  - Microsoft.ContainerService/managedClusters
Deployment B (dependsOn A)
  - Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments
    - contains reference to `nodeResourceGroup` with API version so I made explicit dependsOn for A
```

I plan on using `Azure Pod Identity` so I need to assign that managed identity two roles: `ManagedIdentityOperator` and `VirtualMachineContributor`. I have a variable that builds the path to this identity that is used in a reference:

```
"agentpool-account":[concat(subscription().id, '/resourceGroups/', variables('managedClusterResourceGroup'), '/providers/Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities/', parameters('cluster-name'), '-agentpool')]
```

```
"principalId": "[reference(parameters('agentpool-account'), '2018-11-30', 'full').properties.principalId]",
```

However on the first time I deploy this template (i.e. on cluster creation), the `RoleAssignment` deployment will fail because of a `Resource Group not found` error. Looking at the deployment activity confirms that the `RoleAssignment` is deployed *prior* to the `MC_group` being created despite having an explicit `dependsOn` on the cluster deployment. And if I redeploy the template, it'll succeed because the `MC_group` now exists according to ARM.

I was wondering if anyone else has run into this issue and any tips on how to resolve this would be great. I've come across a link https://bmoore-msft.blog/2020/07/26/resource-not-found-dependson-is-not-working/ but doesn't seem to work for me.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.1",
  "parameters": {
    "cluster-name": {
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The name of the cluster"
      },
      "type": "string"
    },
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "apiVersion": "2019-10-01",
      "location": "centralus",
      "name": "test",
      "type": "Microsoft.Resources/resourceGroups"
    },
    {
      "apiVersion": "2020-06-01",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Resources/resourceGroups', 'test')]"
      ],
      "name": "cluster-deployment",
      "properties": {
        "expressionEvaluationOptions": {
          "scope": "outer"
        },
        "mode": "Incremental",
        "parameters": {},
        "template": {
          "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
          "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
          "outputs": {},
          "parameters": {},
          "resources": [
            {
              "apiVersion": "2019-06-01",
              "dependsOn": [],
              "identity": {
                "type": "SystemAssigned"
              },
              "location": "centralus",
              "name": "[parameters('cluster-name')]",
              "properties": {
                "addonProfiles": {
                  "azurePolicy": {
                    "enabled": false
                  },
                  "httpApplicationRouting": {
                    "enabled": false
                  }
                },
                "agentPoolProfiles": [
                  {
                    "availabilityZones": [
                      "1",
                      "2",
                      "3"
                    ],
                    "count": 3,
                    "maxPods": 110,
                    "mode": "System",
                    "name": "agentpool",
                    "osDiskSizeGB": 0,
                    "osType": "Linux",
                    "storageProfile": "ManagedDisks",
                    "type": "VirtualMachineScaleSets",
                    "vmSize": "Standard_D16s_v3"
                  }
                ],
                "apiServerAccessProfile": {
                  "enablePrivateCluster": false
                },
                "dnsPrefix": "[concat(parameters('cluster-name'), '-dns')]",
                "enableRBAC": true,
                "kubernetesVersion": "1.17.11",
                "networkProfile": {
                  "loadBalancerSku": "standard",
                  "networkPlugin": "kubenet",
                  "networkPolicy": "calico"
                }
              },
              "tags": {},
              "type": "Microsoft.ContainerService/managedClusters"
            }
          ],
          "variables": {}
        }
      },
      "resourceGroup": "test",
      "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments"
    },
    {
      "apiVersion": "2020-06-01",
      "dependsOn": [
        "cluster-deployment"
      ],
      "name": "identity-assignment",
      "properties": {
        "expressionEvaluationOptions": {
          "scope": "outer"
        },
        "mode": "Incremental",
        "template": {
          "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
          "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
          "outputs": {},
          "parameters": {},
          "resources": [
            {
              "apiVersion": "2017-09-01",
              "name": "[guid('test', 'ManagedIdentityOperator')]",
              "properties": {
                "principalId": "[reference(variables('agentpoolResourceId'), '2018-11-30', 'full').properties.principalId]",
                "roleDefinitionId": "[variables('managedIdentityOperatorRoleId')]",
                "scope": "[concat(subscription().id, '/resourceGroups/test')]"
              },
              "type": "Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments"
            },
            {
              "apiVersion": "2017-09-01",
              "name": "[guid('test', 'VirtualMachineContributor')]",
              "properties": {
                "principalId": "[reference(variables('agentpoolResourceId'), '2018-11-30', 'full').properties.principalId]",
                "roleDefinitionId": "[variables('virtualMachineContributorRoleId')]",
                "scope": "[concat(subscription().id, '/resourceGroups/test')]"
              },
              "type": "Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments"
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "resourceGroup": "test",
      "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments"
    }
  ],
  "variables": {
    "agentPoolResourceId": "[concat(subscription().id, '/resourceGroups/', variables('managedClusterResourceGroup'), '/providers/Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities/', parameters('cluster-name'), '-agentpool')]",
    "managedClusterResourceGroup": "[concat('MC_test_', parameters('cluster-name'), '_centralus')]",
    "managedIdentityOperatorRoleId": "[concat(subscription().id, '/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/f1a07417-d97a-45cb-824c-7a7467783830')]",
    "virtualMachineContributorRoleId": "[concat(subscription().id, '/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/9980e02c-c2be-4d73-94e8-173b1dc7cf3c')]"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the attached...  I suspect the problem you ran into is the fact that the systemAssigned identity (aka MSI) has not globally replicated by the time the roleAssignment is performed.  To fix that you can add the `principalType` property to the roleAssigment and that will force the assignment even though the principal (i.e. the MSI) may not be found yet.  That's probably the simple fix.

Aside from that, I changed the template a bit to remove the second deployment so that might show a bigger diff than you actually need, but just a different way to approach it.

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2018-05-01/subscriptionDeploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.1",
    "parameters": {
        "cluster-name": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "mc1"
        },
        "resourceGroupName": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "test"
        }
    },
    "resources": [
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Resources/resourceGroups",
            "apiVersion": "2019-10-01",
            "location": "centralus",
            "name": "[parameters('resourceGroupName')]"
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
            "apiVersion": "2020-06-01",
            "name": "cluster-deployment",
            "resourceGroup": "[parameters('resourceGroupName')]",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[subscriptionResourceId('Microsoft.Resources/resourceGroups', 'test')]"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "expressionEvaluationOptions": {
                    "scope": "inner"
                },
                "mode": "Incremental",
                "parameters": {
                    "cluster-name":{
                        "value": "[parameters('cluster-name')]"
                    }
                },
                "template": {
                    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
                    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
                    "parameters": {
                        "cluster-name": {
                            "type": "string"
                        }
                    },
                    "variables": {
                        "managedIdentityOperatorRoleId": "[subscriptionResourceId('Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions', 'f1a07417-d97a-45cb-824c-7a7467783830')]",
                        "virtualMachineContributorRoleId": "[subscriptionResourceId('Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions', '9980e02c-c2be-4d73-94e8-173b1dc7cf3c')]"
                    },
                    "resources": [
                        {
                            "type": "Microsoft.ContainerService/managedClusters",
                            "apiVersion": "2020-11-01",
                            "name": "[parameters('cluster-name')]",
                            "location": "centralus",
                            "identity": {
                                "type": "SystemAssigned"
                            },
                            "properties": {
                                "addonProfiles": {
                                    "azurePolicy": {
                                        "enabled": false
                                    },
                                    "httpApplicationRouting": {
                                        "enabled": false
                                    }
                                },
                                "agentPoolProfiles": [
                                    {
                                        "availabilityZones": [
                                            "1",
                                            "2",
                                            "3"
                                        ],
                                        "count": 3,
                                        "maxPods": 110,
                                        "mode": "System",
                                        "name": "agentpool",
                                        "osDiskSizeGB": 0,
                                        "osType": "Linux",
                                        "storageProfile": "ManagedDisks",
                                        "type": "VirtualMachineScaleSets",
                                        "vmSize": "Standard_D16s_v3"
                                    }
                                ],
                                "apiServerAccessProfile": {
                                    "enablePrivateCluster": false
                                },
                                "dnsPrefix": "[concat(parameters('cluster-name'), '-dns')]",
                                "enableRBAC": true,
                                "kubernetesVersion": "1.17.11",
                                "networkProfile": {
                                    "loadBalancerSku": "standard",
                                    "networkPlugin": "kubenet",
                                    "networkPolicy": "calico"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments",
                            "apiVersion": "2017-09-01",
                            "name": "[guid('test', 'ManagedIdentityOperator')]",
                            "properties": {
                                "principalId": "[reference(parameters('cluster-name'), '2020-11-01', 'full').identity.principalId]",
                                "roleDefinitionId": "[variables('managedIdentityOperatorRoleId')]",
                                "scope": "[resourceGroup().id]",
                                "principalType": "ServicePrincipal"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments",
                            "apiVersion": "2017-09-01",
                            "name": "[guid('test', 'VirtualMachineContributor')]",
                            "properties": {
                                "principalId": "[reference(parameters('cluster-name'), '2020-11-01', 'full').identity.principalId]",
                                "roleDefinitionId": "[variables('virtualMachineContributorRoleId')]",
                                "scope": "[resourceGroup().id]",
                                "principalType": "ServicePrincipal"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

LMK if you have any questions about the other changes...

Comment: Thanks for the response! In a previous iteration, I was actually using this exact reference to the system-assigned identity. However, when I got to setting up `AAD Pod Identity`, I realized that (by default) the expected managed identity is not the system-assigned one, but rather the user assigned identity in the form of `<cluster-name>-agentpool`. The agentpool account is a resource that lives inside the `MC_group` and the validation that the `MC_group` exists is what is failing for me.

Comment: I have seem to found a way around it and it's a process similar to what I found on your blog. I essentially turned the `ManagedCluster` deployment into an `inner` scope deployment and output `reference('cluster-name').nodeResourceGroup`. I then funnel that value as a parameter to a separate role assignments deployment in the same parent template and things work on first pass.

Comment: Add `"principalType": "ServicePrincipal"` and it works... thanks Brian!    (should be in the docs really)

Comment: you're right it should - where did you look, I'll see if I can get it updated...